# Why does this console log 0?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Can anyone help me with this? I can't understand why this code console logs 0. Thanks

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const observable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
observable
  .switchMap(event => Rx.Observable.timer(1000))
  .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    );
```

Comment: Pen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRZrEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click you switch your button event to the timer Observable via `switchMap`. As a result you get timer event in the subscribe. In your example timer event will be number 0, because it is how timer works.

Have a look at `timer` declaration, it emits numbers starting from 0, but in your case `timer` will just emit one number and stop, you can control this with the second parameter of timer.